# Find the adjacent and opposite side by their ratio and the hypotenuse

Tags: geometry

Consider an right-angled triangle:

```
          /|
         / |
        /  |
      1/   |y
      /   _|
     /___|_|
         x
```

I have the ratio of x and y. It is possible to find their values without any trigonometric functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le $y=kx$ and apply Pythagorean theorem to get $ x^2+ k^2 x^2 =1$

That gives us $$x=\frac {1}{\sqrt {1+k^2}} $$ and   $$y=\frac {k}{\sqrt {1+k^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let x:y = a:b

then bx = ay

represent y as $\frac{b}{a}x$, and let k be b/a.

then use the pythagorean theorem:

$x^2 + k^2x^2 = 1$

simplify,

$x^2(k^2 + 1) = 1$

thus:

$x = \pm \sqrt(\frac{1}{k^2 + 1})$

Comment: As the length can not be a minus value shouldn't we have to neglect the minus case?